# pin_ptr and interior_ptr in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, pin-ptr

I am working on a project that was written(a HID inteface for STM32) by a person who worked before in visual c++ 2008. So to imitate the line that is causing problem, I created a sample winform application in VC++ 2008. Here is the click event with this one line giving build error only when built for x64, but a win32 build doesn't give any building error and works fine.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             String^ devPath =  this->textBox1->Text;
             MessageBox::Show(devPath);
             pin_ptr<const TCHAR> pPath = PtrToStringChars(devPath); *error line
         }
};
```

and the the build error that appears only for x64 build is:

```
Error   1 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'cli::interior_ptr<Type>' to 'cli::pin_ptr<Type>'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not actually, I need to pass that into the CreateFile as the first parameter. And for 32bit it worked, the problem only happens in 64bit. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: PtrToStringChars always returns a const wchar_t; are your 64-bit builds not compiling to Unicode?

Comment: Thanks Sir. I have answered my question. You got it right, I set the character set to unicode. It was set to No Character Set. Also Multi-Byte Character set gave same error message. But Unicode fixed it. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right Click on the project
2. Properties
3. Configuration Properties
4. General
5. Character-Set "Use Unicode Character Set"

This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The "better" solution is probably:

```
pin_ptr<const WCHAR> pPath = PtrToStringChars(devPath);
```

and then use `CreateFileW`, because you have a Unicode string.

That way your code will work regardless of project-file Unicode configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this one out. But I was wondering what does these character set do? Like setting Multi-Byte will not work on all computers? I'm new to these and would appreciate if you point in a direction. Thanks.

Comment: @Vikyboss: It isn't all that important anymore, since most people have upgraded, but Win9x doesn't have full Unicode support.  Multi-byte mode (which is single-byte actually, except for Far-Eastern languages) will run on all versions of Windows, Unicode builds usually only on NT: Win2000, XP, Vista, Win7.  On Win9x, `CreateFileW` isn't available, so you'd actually have to call the Unicode->MBCS conversion function `WideCharToMultiByte` in order to make a usable filename.  Modern versions of Windows can use Unicode filenames directly.